# Is there a way to get 2K resolution without my monitor supporting it?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, display-resolution

I need a way to get 2K resolution on Ubuntu Linux 20.10. My monitor is Dell P2419H with 1920x1080 resolution. On Windows there's an option in the nVIDIA panel that allows me to create and set a custom resolution. On Linux however, I can't find a solution that allows me to set a custom resolution to my main monitor. I've tried messing with the font scaling however it's not ideal since the fonts start looking weird. It's worth mentioning that I have a dual monitor setup with my laptop's screen and my monitor (both of which are 1920x1080). I want a solution that applies 2K only to my main monitor.

Comment: "2K resolution" is an arbitrary term since it isn't really defined.  I'm not sure what you actually want to do.  If you have an LCD/LED panel, anything except the native resolution is going to look bad. Why don't you try adjusting elements of the UI instead?  You might want to use a different DE than GNOME, since GNOME is not very easy to customize.

Comment: @Nmath I want to get the screen estate of 2560x1440 on my 1920x1080 monitor.

Comment: It's not possible without font antialiasing, which is going to make fonts look really bad, as you've discovered.  Pixels are not divisible, except into subpixels.   Fonts also look really bad (fuzzy) on Windows using NVIDIA's "super resolution", so I'm not sure you can get what you want without getting a higher resolution display.

Comment: @Nmath Nah, on Windows it works just fine. I set the resolution to 2560x1440 and Windows automatically scales at 125%. There could be bluryness but I can't really tell since I've been using this for a long time. On Linux, the best solution I've found so far is setting the ViewPortIn and Panning to 2048x1152 which achieves the same effect as on Windows after the scaling. It's blurrier than on Windows which I kind of fixed by increasing the monitor's sharpness from the OSD.